# Concat every 4 strings from a list?

Tags: python, string, list, ip

I have this list:

```
['192', '168', '0', '1', '80', '192', '168', '0', '2', '8080']...
```

And i want to get this list:

```
['192.168.0.1:80', '192.168.0.2:8080']...
```

What is the best way of doing it ?

using `range` with `list` pop ?

using `list` slicing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> data = ['192', '168', '0', '1', '80', '192', '168', '0', '2', '8080']
>>> ['{}.{}.{}.{}:{}'.format(*x) for x in zip(*[iter(data)]*5)]
['192.168.0.1:80', '192.168.0.2:8080']
```

Using `starmap`

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap('{}.{}.{}.{}:{}'.format,zip(*[iter(data)]*5)))
['192.168.0.1:80', '192.168.0.2:8080']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it, which may or may not be the "best" way:

```
>>> a = ['192', '168', '0', '1', '80', '192', '168', '0', '2', '8080']
>>> [":".join([".".join(a[x:x+4]), a[x+4]]) for x in range(0, len(a), 5)]
['192.168.0.1:80', '192.168.0.2:8080']
```